# How do I associate an edit I made anonymously with my newly created user account?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, user-accounts, anonymous

So I made an edit to an answer on History Stack Exchange. After saving, the site encouraged me to create a user account, which I immediately did. But the original edit I made is still anonymous, and only appears on the page when I log out of my account (since it is still awaiting review). This is infuriating. How do I associate the edit I originally made with my newly created user account? This should be automatic, or at least simple to do.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to the network! Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible. But any edits you make from now on will be under your account.

It takes a little while for edits to be reviewed because it takes two users to review it. Users need a certain amount of reputation to be able to review edits, too.

[Is this your edit?](https://history.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/27383) It's already been approved. Everyone, including you, should be able to see the edit.

For more information about editing, read [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/323179).

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thank you!